# takeUntil with previously dispatched action cancels an effect request

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

In my scenario, when the user selects an order:

```
selectOrder(orderId): void {
  this.store$.dispatch(
    selectOrder({orderId})
  );
}
```

the order UI component dispatches an action in order to load all related data:

```
private getOrderOnSelectOrder(): void {
  this.store$.select(selectSelectedOrder).pipe(filter((selectedOrder: Order | null): selectedOrder is Order => Boolean(selectedOrder)))
    .subscribe((selectedOrder: Order) => {
      this.store$.dispatch(getOrder({
        orderId: selectedOrder.id
      }))
    }
  );
}
```

An effect is waiting for this action to make a request to the server:

```
public getOrder$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(getOrder),
            switchMap((props: GetOrderProps) =>
                this.orderService.getOrder(props.orderId).pipe(
                    map((order: Order) =>
                        /* Logic for successfully received order */
                    ),
                    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) =>
                        /* Logic for failure */
                    ),
                    takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(selectOrder))),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Please notice the `takeUntil` line, the issue appears therein. I added it to discard the request on select a new order as we do not need its result at this point anymore. To my little surprise it causes any request to be cancelled immediately, so I can't get orders at all.

Why does this behavior take place? To my understading of the things, a request hits *after* the select order action, why then its corresponding observable gets affected by it?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the `takeUntil`?

`switchMap` will already cancel a pending request, and fetches the orders of the new selected order.

Comment: I realize it but it is possible that the order UI component, which dispatches actions that cancel the pending requests, will not be rendered immediately after order selection. Anyway, I'd like to get my mind around this behavior.